# Maven is not using dependency version specified in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have a project A, which has B and C dependencies.
The project B also depends on C.

In project A pom, I have:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            <version>2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>BVERSION</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            <version>2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
```

In project B(version `BVERSION`), I have:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have added some methods in C dependency in version 2, but the code doesn't compile when I try to use the new methods. That is, I can't access the new methods. Project A is using version 1(which is inside project B) of C.

If I change the order of the import in project A pom from `B, C` to `C, B`, the code compiles, but at execution time a get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` error.

Shouldn't maven `dependencyManagement` deal with this problem and force project A to use version 2 of C? Does anyone have an idea of what  I am getting wrong?

EDIT 1:

`mvn dependency:tree` returns the following:

```
[INFO] br.com.mygroup:A:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- br.com.mygroup:B:jar:BVERSION:compile
[INFO] +- br.com.mygroup:C:jar:2:compile
```

EDIT 2:

`mvn dependency:list` returns the following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< br.com.mygroup:A >---------------------
[INFO] Building A 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ A ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    br.com.mygroup:B:jar:BVERSION:compile
[INFO]    br.com.mygroup:C:jar:2:compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.639 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-04T09:03:37-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please call `mvn dependency:tree` and add the result to your question.

Comment: If you don't have a parent POM, you get version 2. And `mvn dependency:list` should also show that.

Comment: are you using spring boot here?

Comment: @JFMeier I have added the `mvn dependency:tree` result to the question.
@MariuszS I am using jersey.

Comment: Then you should have version 2 in your project.

Comment: That's why I'am crazy :/

Comment: Please also run `dependency:list` and give me the output.

Comment: @JFMeier added :)

Comment: This means that you _definitely_ have version 2 in your project. Your errors most likely come from somewhere else. Maybe you did not include the right code into version 2 or confused some other things. Maybe some classes in different jars have the same qualified names, so that you are not accessing the class you think you access.

Comment: Especially: Are you sure that jars B and C have no overlap in qualified class names and none of them is a "fat jar" (includes dependencies)?

Comment: Java classpaths are "flat", i.e., there's no "this dependency uses this version, this other dependency uses this other version". If you have two versions of the same dependency you are at the mercy of the JRE's load order. You can [explicitly *exclude* a dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions). This can lead to a host of *other* problems, of course, if there are breaking changes between versions.

Comment: @JFMeier yes, I'm sure. B is only an api client package. C is my package with database models. A is the main package with business rules. At compilation time I get the correct version 2 of C. My problem is at Runtime.

Comment: So how do you run your program? Is a war? Is it a standalone jar?

Comment: @JFMeier the war is deployed with tomcat

Comment: And you inspected your war and looked at the included jars?

Comment: @JFMeier yes, inside war there is the package C, on version 2, in `/WEB-INF/lib/C-2.jar`

Comment: Then this is what you get at runtime. I guess you are looking at the wrong place for the error you got.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I'm getting ate execution time :/

Comment: Can you really _prove_ that version 2 is not loaded at runtime?

Comment: My prove is the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` I'm getting at execution time.